# How to change vue.js data value when screen size changes?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, skel

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <!-- On mobile devices use short heading -->
        <template v-if="mobile == 1">
            <li><a href="#">Heading</a></li>
        </template>
        <!-- Else use long heading -->
        <template v-else-if="mobile == 0">
            <li><a href="#">Heading Long</a></li>
        </template>
    </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                mobile: 0
            }
});
```

I'm looking for a way to change the value of 'mobile' when the screen breakpoint of (max-width: 547px) becomes active. And to change it back when this mobile breakpoint becomes inactive (screen goes over 547px). I normally use skel (https://github.com/ajlkn/skel) to deal with screen breakpoints, but I cannot access skel from inside Vue, or vice-versa. I would forego using Vue for this particular task, but display: none, and display: block throws off my presentation--turning my element into a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this library : https://github.com/apertureless/vue-breakpoints

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <!-- On mobile devices use short heading -->
        <hide-at breakpoint="medium">
        <template v-if="mobile == 1">
            <li><a href="#">Heading</a></li>
        </template>
        </hide-at>
        <!-- Else use long heading -->
        <show-at breakpoint="mediumAndAbove">
        <template v-else-if="mobile == 0">
            <li><a href="#">Heading Long</a></li>
        </template>
        </show-at>
    </ul>
</div>
```

or simply go with `media queries` (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

**CSS :**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #app ul il:first-of-type {
        visibility: visible;
    }
    #app ul il:last-of-type {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}


@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    #app ul il:first-of-type {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #app ul il:last-of-type {
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

ofcourse it's up to you to decide what to show and what to hide on what breakpoint , i hope this helps.

Comment: I had no idea about this library. And by the way, you don't have to use v-if on the templates anymore--I only used those to 'display: none;'. Also, I figured out there is another value for the 'display' attribute, called 'inline' (display: inline). I used it to fix the presentation problem I was having with 'display: block'. Thanks for the answer. I will be using this library quite a bit from now on.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/breakpoints/), you can programmatically adjust the data value based on the built in `breakpoints` of xs, sm, md, lg, xl (as specified in [Material Design](https://material.io/design/layout/responsive-layout-grid.html#breakpoints)) as follows:

```
computed: {
  mobile() {
    return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.sm
  },
}
```

`mobile` will change to `true` as soon as the screen width is less than 600px.

Your code would then be something like this (I also moved the `if` statement to be directly on the `<li>` element):

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <!-- On mobile devices use short heading -->
        <li v-if="mobile"><a href="#">Heading</a></li>
        <!-- Else use long heading -->
        <li v-else><a href="#">Heading Long</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [onorientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange) event like the following:

```js
methods: {
   detectOrientationChange() {
      switch(window.orientation) {  
         case -90 || 90:
            // landscape
            this.mobile = false;
            break; 
         default:
            // portrait
            this.mobile = true;
            break; 
      }
   }
},
mounted() {
   this.$nextTick(() => {
      window.addEventListener('onorientationchange', this.detectOrientationChange)
   }
},
created() {
   this.detectOrientationChange(); // when instance is created
}
```

**Note**: As the event has been deprecated, it can only be used with mobile browsers as of writing this.

---

To detect screen orientation on current browsers [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67961837/deprecated-window-orientationchange-event).

Comment: You may also need to hook the method inside`beforeDestroy`