# Deprecated: Window: orientationchange event

Tags: javascript

The [orientationchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event) event has been deprecated.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function(event) {
  console.log(event.target.screen.orientation.angle);
});
```

## Window: orientationchange event

> **Deprecated**
> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

What can I use now? Is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use experimental feature [ScreenOrientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/onchange)

```
screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', function(e) { ... })
screen.orientation.onchange = function(e) { ... }
```

You can check the available values from [screen orientation table](https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/#dfn-screen-orientation-values-table) for orientation types:

- portrait-primary
- portrait-secondary
- landscape-primary
- landscape-secondary

Here's an example:

```
screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.currentTarget.type === 'landscape-primary') {
    // landscape mode => angle 0
  } else if (e.currentTarget.type === 'portrait-primary') {
    // portrait mode => angle 0
  }
})
```

Check [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScreenOrientation/onchange#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Yet another thing Safari lags on being compatible with...

Comment: Coz, it's still experimental feature.

Comment: @RaisinBranCrunch `window.orientation` seems to work latest cross browser

Answer (score 0):

`window.orientation`

Still seems to work. I guess you can use

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
  if (Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90) {
    // landscape mode => angle 90 or -90
  } else if (window.orientation == 0) {
    // portrait mode => angle 0
  }
})
```

If you your target is strictly mobile

Comment: It is deprecated only not removed. in future it will be removed.

Comment: I don't think it ever will. It will remain one of those deprecated apis that are never put away for good because it already has so much adoption. Nobody cares if it's deprecated, it's good and it works as expected, so everybody uses it.